# How to handle user permission base on role?

Tags: reactjs, permissions

I'm creating an Admin Dashboard with React, and manage access base on user role (Admin, Client and User). Each role will have permission like:

- Admin: can view Dashboard and CRUD posts
- Client: can view Dashboard and create and read posts
- User: can't view Dashboard and only read posts

Is there a way to implement this or npm package that supports with role n permission like this?

thanks!

this is demo code
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shape-6mvos?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

**In your case to handle react rendering your best chose is** [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/)

By NextJs you can controller your rendering page before sending to your client

Comment: yeah, but I'm doing with react and switch to Next may take many effort

Comment: on this case you want to know how to render your components by express js by using rsr 
this link maybe helpful: [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering ]

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this every day. I have a component called Permission. It takes in the name of the permission(s) as a prop and checks to see if the user (stored in redux) has those permissions. If so, it returns the children of the Permission component.

Permission.js:

```
const Permission = ({ allowedPermissions, children }) => {
   function isVisible() {
       let visible = true;
       allowedPermission.forEach((permission) => { 
           if (!user.permissions.includes(permission) {
               visible = false;  
           }
       });
       return visible;
   }

   return isVisible() ? children : null;
}
```

Usage, which can include being wrapped around react-router switch/route statements:

```
<Permission allowedPermissions=["admin"]>
    <Button onClick={() => deletePost()}>Delete</Button>
</Permission>
```

Comment: look like it work for me, I defined a list of permissions and scopes, then using hook to check allowPermission, and the rest similar to you.